# Weird PHP error when removing commments

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the following piece of code: (First line is number 172)

```
                if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
            {

                $buyerName = $httpParsedResponseAr["FIRSTNAME"].' '.$httpParsedResponseAr["LASTNAME"];
                $buyerEmail = $httpParsedResponseAr["EMAIL"];
                /*
                //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
                $mysqli = new mysqli('My stuff, not giving you meh passwords xD');

                //Output any connection error
                if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
                }       

                $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO BuyerTable 
                (BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,ItemAmount)
                VALUES ('$buyerName','$buyerEmail','$transactionID',$ItemTotalPrice);

                if($insert_row){
                    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />'; 
                }else{
                    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                }
                */

                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
                echo '</pre>';
            } else  {
                echo '<div style="color:red"><b>GetTransactionDetails failed:</b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
                echo '</pre>';

            }
```

See that multi-line comment? When I remove it, there is the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'color' (T_STRING) in *path to file* on line 201
```

I have no idea what would cause this, since line 201 is

```
echo '<div style="color:red"><b>GetTransactionDetails failed:</b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
```

There is no 'color' inside it even! Please help me with this, I have no idea what to do anymore. Also tried commenting out that line, no effect. Is it a bug in the system or in my code?

Comment: you would need to show the contents of `$httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]` in order for us to see if this is the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing the last double quote on your sql statement here after $ItemTotalPrice

```
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO BuyerTable 
                (BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,ItemAmount)
                VALUES ('$buyerName','$buyerEmail','$transactionID',$ItemTotalPrice);
```

Comment: that code is all commented out. Why would that be the problem?

Comment: ah! you got it. nice.. guess the commented code meant to be uncommented